Is there any way to restart a script that I closed with ^D in linux
I am new to Linux and am trying it first in wsl2.
I started a script with script command which recorded my shell activities, but after I closed it with ^D, I realized I forgot to record another activity in that script. So is there any way to make that script start again
I tried ./Script1.part1 and sudo systemctl restart Script1.part1. Apparently I couldn't find the solution

As  you say "I forgot to record another activity", if you just rerun your with script -a ... you'll run all steps in your original code. (Maybe that is OK, then don't bother with -a). Before re-running edit your code and comment out any steps that where completed. Good luck.

Running
script -a script1.part1
will append to your script retaining the existing content.
